# Problem with Cypress during VUE installation

Tags: vue.js, cypress, yarn-v2

I am trying to install Vue, with Vue UI and after many errors, the command line stops working at the last error;

```
 {"type":"warning","data":"\"@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress > eslint-plugin-cypress@2.12.1\" has unmet peer dependency \"eslint@>= 3.2.1\"."}
```

after many fails I give up to use VUE UI, and tried to create vue file with **vue create** command and command-line keeps loading since 20 mins;

```
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[1/1] ⠂ cypress
```

I think the problem at Cypress testing module, I dont know how to solve this installation problem, its been a whole day i am trying to use yarn to create an application. I tried to installed npm and node again but didnt help

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: What are you aiming to do?

Comment: this command also thrown an error : uuid@3.4.0  and  @hapi/hoek@8.5.1 deprecated.